# Use multiple forms in one project with React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two separate files with two separate components. I want to have two independent instances of form in each of them. In each component form is implemented as shown in the docs [here](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started) so using **useForm** hook. React throws me the error which says:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

I discovered that's because I have the **useForm** hook declared multiple times (in each component). If I removed one form, the project compiles and works as supposed to (with one form only).
The question is - how can I implement two separate and independent instances of form in multiple components?

I guess it's unnecessary to attach code, it's logical problem with implementation, the code is correct.

Comment: Please check again all your component imports. Sometimes this error can be fixed by importing component again even with the same line of import * from ''

Comment: "I guess it's unnecessary to attach code, it's logical problem with implementation, the code is correct." If the code was correct it would be working. Please show the code

Comment: https://controlc.com/6336ab37
https://controlc.com/18c0acc2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class component needs to be converted to functional component

```
const WelcomeBlock = () => {
  const { register, handleSumbit } = useForm();
  return (
    <StyledContainer>
      <StyledLogo src={logo} alt="FavNote" />
      <Heading big>Your new favorite online note experience</Heading>
      <StyledWrapper>
        <Heading big>Sign in</Heading>
        <StyledForm onSubmit={handleSumbit()}>
          <Input {...register('login')} placeholder="Login" />
          <Input {...register('password')} placeholder="Password" />
          <Button type="submit">Enter Favnote</Button>
        </StyledForm>
        <Paragraph>
          Are you here for the first time? Let's
          <Button sec>Create new account</Button>
        </Paragraph>
      </StyledWrapper>
    </StyledContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you, that was the problem, also some stupid misspelling such as "sumbit"
sorry

Comment: happens to everyone)